# switching kubernetes CNI from weave to calico

Tags: kubernetes, weave, calico

i installed a `kubeadm` v1.17 cluster with weave initially. I would like to switch it over to use calico. However, as i originally did not install the cluster with

```
kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16
```

as per the docs, but with a simple

```
kubeadm init
```

i was wondering what steps i need to perform to achieve the transition from weave to calico?

Answer (score 2):

To change CNI from Weave Net to Calico in the cluster you can do the following:

Delete weave-net pods configuration:

```
kubectl delete -f "https://cloud.weave.works/k8s/net?k8s-version=$(kubectl version | base64 | tr -d '\n')"
```

Then change podCIDR by running following command on your master node:

```
sudo kubeadm init phase control-plane controller-manager --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16
```

`192.168.0.0/16` is the default podCIDR used by Calico and can be changed **only once.**

If you try to change it afterwards it will show error:

> spec.podCIDRs: Forbidden: node updates may not change podCIDR except
>   from "" to valid

so it's one way operation.

After that you can apply calico:

```
kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.11/manifests/calico.yaml
```

Additionally if you choose to set different podCIDR you have to specify podCIDR in `kubeadm init`:

```
sudo kubeadm init phase control-plane all --pod-network-cidr=<your_podCIDR>
```

then modify Calico DaemonSet:

```
...
- name: CALICO_IPV4POOL_CIDR
value: "<your_podCIDR>"
...
```

and then apply it. But as mentioned before, you cannot do it once the podCIDR was specified. It can be added but cannot be modified later.

Comment: are the CNI and kubernetes  pod CIDR be the same range?  I thought they are supposed to be separate ranges?